# linking a large sqlite database with a listview android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

I have my own sqlite database that i have successfully been able to load into my project and it correctly loads onto the device on first execution.
Now the problem i'm facing is to display all 4000 rows in the database onto a simple listview.
Can someone please tell me how i can use the database present to read entries and link it with the listview.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try a partial load concept, after scrolls near the maximum line then load the other interval of the rows from database.

Answer (score 0):

Your question was  a bit vague, but I think you're looking for a ListView and a CuursorAdapter. That is, assuming your data has been converted to a SQLite DB, of course.

See [this page of the dev guide](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex1.html).